# AZURE SQL cross server database backup or Query

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

As I am in the beginner level to handle the Azure SQL and I struggled to take the database backup or cross query from Azure SQL server A to server B.  Can anyone help me to achieving the task.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Please give details

Comment: Not unless you explain what you want. Backups aren't queries. What do you mean `cross query` anyway? There is no such thing. There are linked servers and queries that use them

Comment: As for backups, did you read the Azure SQL documentation? Do you want to ask something that *isn't* there? Did you actually *try* to take a backup with SSMS ?

Comment: CREATE DATABASE serverA.XXXX AS COPY OF serverB.XXXX;